# Thread-6, RECV TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, groovy, certificate

what is wrong with this code, it is supposed to trust all hosts, but it doesn't..

It works fine with for example google.com but not with an API Gateway service running locally on my machine, why?

**SSL DEBUG OUTPUT**

> trigger seeding of SecureRandom done seeding SecureRandom Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 ...
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   Allow unsafe renegotiation: false Allow legacy hello messages: true Is
>   initial handshake: true Is secure renegotiation: false Thread-6,
>   setSoTimeout(0) called %% No cached client session
>   *** ClientHello, TLSv1 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1434280256 bytes = { 216 ... 40 } Session ID:  {} Cipher Suites:
>   [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, ....
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,
>   TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] Compression Methods:  { 0 }
>   Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1 .. secp256k1}
>   Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
>
> Thread-6, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163 Thread-6, READ: TLSv1
>   Alert, length = 2 Thread-6, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal,
>   handshake_failure Thread-6, called closeSocket() Thread-6, handling
>   exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: **
>
> Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

---

**

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class ConnectHttps {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    /*
     *  fix for
     *    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
     *       sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
     *           PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
     *               unable to find valid certification path to requested target
     */
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = [
        [ getAcceptedIssuers: { -> null },
          checkClientTrusted: { X509Certificate[] certs, String authType -> },
          checkServerTrusted: { X509Certificate[] certs, String authType -> } ] as X509TrustManager
    ]

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          return true;
        }
    };
    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    /*
     * end of the fix
     */

    //URL url = new URL("https://google.com"); //WORKS
    URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8090");   // DOES NOT WORK, WHY?
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
    while (true) {
      int ch = reader.read();
      if (ch==-1) {
        break;
      }
      System.out.print((char)ch);
    }
  }
}
```

Running [the code found here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1314113) it shows that TLSv1.2 is not enabled on the client side:

> Supported Protocols: 5
>   SSLv2Hello
>   SSLv3
>   TLSv1
>   TLSv1.1
>   TLSv1.2
>
> Enabled Protocols: 2
>   SSLv3
>   TLSv1

Answer (score 6):

> .. it is supposed to trust all hosts, but it doesn't..
>
> .. RECV TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure Thread-6

A handshake failure alert from the server is unrelated to the validation of the servers certificate on the client and can thus not stopped by disabling certificate validation. Lots of things can cause such a failure, like no common ciphers, unsupported protocol version, missing SNI extension (only supported starting with JDK7). Since the error is issued by the server you might find more details about the problem in the servers log messages.

EDIT: from the server logs the cause of the problem is visible:

> error handling connection: SSL protocol error error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher

This means that there is no common cipher between client and server.

A typical cause for this is a wrong setup of the certificates at the server. If you don't configure any certificates the server might require anonymous authentication with ADH ciphers, which are usually not enabled on the client side. I suggest that you check if you could connect with a browser.

Another common misconfiguration is disabling all SSLv3 ciphers at the server in the believe that this is necessary to disable the SSL3.0 protocol (it is not). This effectively disables all ciphers except some new ciphers introduced with TLS 1.2. Modern browsers will be still able to connect but older clients not. This misconfiguration can be seen in this case (from the comment):

> From server log,, interface ciphers: FIPS:!SSLv3:!aNULL,,

`!SSLv3` disables all ciphers available for version SSL3.0 **and higher**. This in effect leaves only the TLS1.2 ciphers because there are no new ciphers with TLS1.0 and TLS1.1. Since the client seems to be only support TLS1.0 there will be no shared ciphers:

> ...WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake

Use of `!SSLv3` in the ciphers is usually caused by a lack of understanding of the difference between protocol version and ciphers. To disable SSLv3 you should only set the protocol accordingly but not the ciphers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the server logs, however they dont make me much wiser....  ERROR   14/Jun/2015:13:56:03.746 [00cc] [SSL alert write 00000228, 00002112]: handshake failure [fatal].
ERROR   14/Jun/2015:13:56:03.746 [00cc] [SSL_accept, 00002112]: error - SSLv3 read client hello C.
ERROR   14/Jun/2015:13:56:03.746 [00cc] [SSL_accept, 00002112]: error - SSLv3 read client hello C.
ERROR   14/Jun/2015:13:56:03.747 [00cc] error handling connection: SSL protocol error
        error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher, source location: .\ssl\s3_srvr.c:1360

Comment: @user955732: server log shows the problem. See edited answer.

Comment: @user955732: Then you should check which ciphers are configured at the server (look at the server configuration) and make sure that at least one of these ciphers is available at the client. See edit for more information.

Comment: From server log,, interface ciphers: FIPS:!SSLv3:!aNULL,, tried to set the https.protocols property on the client side,, System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello"); ,, but still no luck...

Comment: @user955732: `!SSLv3` for the ciphers is exactly the thing which is wrong. See edited answer.

Comment: SETTING System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"); AND SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); GIVES "handshake_failure" ... really don't know how to solve this..

Comment: @user955732: I'm not sure if your client is able to do better than TLS1.0 at all (JDK version?). And again, the problem is the `!SSLv3` in the cipher settings on the server side. Please remove it.

Comment: Currently using java 1.7.0_21, not sure if that could be an issue or not. Ideally !SSLv3 should stay on server side, its the default configuration and last option is to remove it.

Comment: Using `!SSLv3` as a setting for ciphers shows no understanding of the difference between protocol version and ciphers. This settings effectively limits access to TLS 1.2 clients. JDK1.7 does not enable TLS1.2 on the client side by default, see http://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7.  And even when TLS1.2 is explicitly enabled the new TLS1.2 ciphers might not be supported. To disable SSLv3 remove it only from `https.protocols`, not from ciphers.

Comment: I edited the question, just as you said, it appears that TLSv1.2 is not enabled on the client side... any ideas how to enable it? Setting the mentioned System properties on superuser.com does not help...

Comment: @user955732: how about just reading the question at superuser I've linked to in my previous comment? And again, it might be that the newer TLS1.2 cipher are not supported even if the protocol is TLS1.2. In this case it will still not work.