# How to Disable TLSv1.2 in Java 8

Tags: java, security, ssl, tls1.2, java-security

Any one know how to disable TLSv1.2 and 1.1 in JRE 8 and only allow to use TLSv1. I have already tried -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1" parameter but no luck. As I look at the SSL debugger out put I can see still using the V1.2

```
00E0: 05 01 04 03 04 01 03 03   03 01 02 03 02 01 02 02  ................
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
AWT-EventQueue-0, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
AWT-EventQueue-0, RECV **TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure**
AWT-EventQueue-0, called closeSocket()
AWT-EventQueue-0, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
AWT-EventQueue-0, called close()
AWT-EventQueue-0, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable this?  This is unclear to me.

Comment: A quick search may reveal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828759/thread-6-recv-tlsv1-alert-fatal-handshake-failure as a explanation.

Comment: I'm having a server that only support TLSv1, where I get the above error when trying to connect after using Java 8 JRE, but for Java 7 JRE the client can connect without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check your server's simulated handshake with default Java 1.7 and 1.8 clients using a tool like [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html). The handshake error you're seeing may not be related to the TLS version (as TLSv1.2 clients that also support TLSv1.0 should be able to communicate with servers that only communicate using TLSv1.0) and is most likely due to the server using cipher suites that are no longer supported by Java 1.8 (e.g., RC4).

Comment: +1: I want to add [the reference](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, As you said that was a cipher suite related matter, now I need to enable following ciphers in Java 8 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, Tried Editing the java.security file and removing RC4 and adding -Dhttps.cipherSuites="TLS_E.." parameters already, but no luck. Any Idea about this?, Thanks again for directing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Consider modifying `java.security` file.

Depending on your machine:

> The default values of security properties are read from an implementation-specific location, which is typically the properties file lib/security/java.security in the Java installation directory.

[image: java.security]