# How to change TLS version from 1.1 to 1.2 in SOAP UI

Tags: ssl, soapui, tls1.2

UPDATED -

[image]I have almost tried everything so that my TLS version can be changed to 1.2 from 1.1. However, whenever I check for version under **preference** in **SOAP UI**, it only shows two values, 1.1 and 1.0. I have tried the below things that were mostly accepted by people who had faced similar issue. I am currently using **5.4.0**[image] version of SOAP UI

```
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

I have added the above line under SOAP's vmOption file and under the batch file as well. But it didn't worked. I still am getting https response as TLS 1.1 status.

Does anyone know how my SOAP UI version can be changed to TLS 1.2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It clearly says 'HTTP version' and that's what it is. That bears no relation at all to the TLS version. The TLS version is negotiated between the client and server and both need to be properly configured to achieve TLS 1.2

Comment: Sry, I cannot share the screen shot of that but yeah I was getting HTTP 1.1 Status OK when called from HTTPS url to fetch the data. I was getting success status but TLS 1.1 was shown

Answer (score 3):

The following parameter must be added to the soapUI vmoptions file in soapUI's bin directory:

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2

Comment: there is no file named "vmoptions" or soapuivmoptions" in version 5.4 @Brian Houy

Comment: this file on my computer e.g. is called SoapUI-5.6.0.vmoptions, but the correct option that worked successfully to force SoapUI use earlier TLS version is -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1" (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685426/how-to-disable-tlsv1-2-in-java-8)